# Operation Error no such column DJANGO pythonanywhere

Tags: django, sqlite

So i have made change in my model. I added possibility to add picture. It works fine on my computer, but when i try to apply it on internet on pythonanywhere it does not work properly. There even in admin panel i can not add recipe. I have tried delete migrations and migrate again, but it did not help.. Now the website on the intrnet does not work, but on my local server everything is fine.. I do not know how fix it.

My website: http://lui93.pythonanywhere.com/accounts/search/?q=sok

```
OperationalError at /accounts/search/
no such column: drinks_recipe.recipe_image

OperationalError at /accounts/search/
no such column: drinks_recipe.recipe_image
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://lui93.pythonanywhere.com/accounts/search/?q=sok
Django Version: 2.0.13
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such column: drinks_recipe.recipe_image
Exception Location: /home/Lui93/.virtualenvs/lui93.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 305
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.5.6
Python Path:    
['/home/Lui93/lui93.pythonanywhere.com',

Error during template rendering
In template /home/Lui93/lui93.pythonanywhere.com/drinks/templates/drinks/search_results.html, error at line 14

no such column: drinks_recipe.recipe_image
```

my models:

```
from django.db import models


class Ingredient(models.Model):

  ingredient_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.ingredient_name


class Recipe(models.Model):

  recipe_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  preparation = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
  ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)
  recipe_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='')


  def __str__(self):
    return self.recipe_name
```

templates:

```
<body>
    <div id=container>
      <h1><a href="/">Wróć do strony głównej</a></h1>


    {% if results %}
      {% for drink in results %}
          <p><b>{{ drink.recipe_name }}</b></p>
          <p><u>Preparation:</u> {{ drink.preparation }}</p>
          <p><u>Ingredients:</u>
            {% for ingredient in drink.ingredients.all %}
              {{ingredient.ingredient_name}}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </p>
          <p><img src="{{drink.recipe_image.url}}" alt="{{drink.recipe_name}}"</p>
      {% endfor %}

    {% else %}
      Such ingredients do not exist
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Deleting migrations doesn't help - now your database and the migration files are out of sync with each other. If you are still developing your project, the easiest solution is to drop the database on Python Anywhere then run migrate on a fresh database. Back up any data in the db you need before dropping the database.

Comment: do you mean that i should delete mine pythonanywhere website now, and create the new one?

Comment: I’m suggesting you drop the database, not the site. With sqlite you do that by removing the `db.sqlite3` file. Back it up first if you need any data from it.

Comment: I see this folder db.sqlite3 in myp project on my computer. I can not see this file at pythonanywhere or my git.. so it is unclear for me :(

Comment: The traceback shows `sqlite3`, so there should be a database file. It isn’t usually checked into git. Your `DATABASES` setting will tell you the name of the file, it is `db.sqlite3` by default. If you can’t locate that file, then I’m afraid I don’t have any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Django will halt and complain if a model has fields declared, not yet present in the database schema. Either comment the ImageField definition in your model or run python3 manage.py makemigrations and python3 manage.py migrate.

Comment: I did it, and it did not help on internet. On my local server it works properly.

Comment: Double check that in the shell.
1) manage.py dbshell
2) .schema TABLE_NAME

Is the field recipe_image there?

Comment: when i try manage.py dbshell in my windowshell i get Suggestion [3,General]: The command manage.py was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\manage.py". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.